# List records from 1 Google sheet into another google sheet based upon criteria

Tags: google-sheets

Let me start by saying this, I have very minimal Excel knowledge. If my question seems not proper for stack overflow, please guide me where else to look (or which terms to use to google).

I have two sheets. I want to access Sheet B and through columns A1:A32 per se. If Cell A1 contains 'yes', then I want to paste A1, B1, C1, D1 into Sheet A. So basically, if 16 cells out of the 32 in column A of Sheet B have 'yes', then there will be 16 records in Sheet A.

I don't know where to even begin to do this. I've googled a bit and stumbled across VLookup, but not 100% sure how to apply it.

EDIT:

Sheet A - Empty

Sheet B - 
Columns: istrue,Name,X,Y

Comment: Please clarify how your data is laid out - give a full-fledged example of what each sheet looks like.

Comment: why the down vote? Because mis-tagged? And I understand how range defining works, just now how the initial function would look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do either of these two formulae work as you want:

`=FILTER(Sheet2!A:D,Sheet2!A:A="yes")`

`=QUERY(Sheet2!A:D,"where A = 'yes'")` (note that the 'yes' is case-sensitive)